# reduce i/o time for large image hf5 files using mpi

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, hdf5, h5py, mpi4py

I'm trying to reduce the processing time spent on i/o during parallel processing of large images.

**Data:** I have a large `hdf5` file. The datasets contain large images (~14Gb) as `numpy` arrays

**Machine:** Server with shared file system and 12 computing nodes each of which has 28 cores. Each nodes has 256Gb of RAM and has a 150Gb of SSD HD accessible only from the cores part of the node.

**Procedure**
 1. Open the `hdf5` file stored in the common HD
 2. Each core reads a dataset/image
 3. Each core processes the image
 4. The resulting image is saved in the `hdf5`

**Issue**
When I run the code the large part of the processing time is spent in i/o calls and in waiting for HD access. In order to decrease the time spend in writing I though to 'fill' the shared RAM by writing the processed images in a temporary `dictionary` an then write it in the `hdf5`. If I understood the system correctly by doing so I will reduce `n` i/o calls to 1.
I will test the effect on speed but because I am not an expert in optimisation/computer architecture I would like to know:

**Questions**
1) What will be the best strategy to reduce writing time.
2) Is there a way to make use of the SSD HD in order to improve performance?

If the topic doesn't fit stackoverflow please let me know where I should re-post it.

Thanks

---

Added some code showing the read/write steps. In this example read and write happen on the same `hdf5` file but in different groups.

**CODE**

```
# Open reading file (all ranks)
data_file_hdl=h5py.File('RawData.hdf5','r+',driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD,libver='latest')  

# Create a saving group
saving_group=data_file_hdl.create_group('processed_data')

# Create the datasets (all ranks)
ImgSize=(69,2048,2048)
for pos in img_list:
    saving_group.create_dataset(pos,ImgSize,dtype=np.uint16,chunks=(1,ImgSize[1],ImgSize[2]))
data_file_hdl.flush()

# I then scatter the list of images to the each core.
# Each core will have a variable called xlocal that will have a str that 
# correspond to the dataset to load 
# ex. 
# Core1 xlocal= [1,10,20,50]
# Core2 xlocal=[22,33]

for idx in xlocal:
    # Load the image
    ImgStack=data_file_hdl['RawData_grp'][idx].value

    # Processing steps
    ------------------

    # Save the image
    saving_group[idx]=ImgStack
```

`

Comment: Regarding the input image data, do you used all of it exactly once, or do some of the tasks use overlapping input data?  Which part do you think takes more time now: the reading at the beginning or the writing at the end?  What is the total size of all input data and all output data?

Comment: Thanks! Each image is used only once. The total size of the dataset I am using now is around 220 images and the hdf5 is 50Gb (after compression). I will have the same amount of images in the output but the new file will be smaller ~20Gb (after compression). I think that the bottleneck is the writing at the end.

Comment: OK, so you think the writing is the slow part.  Please post the code you use for writing, including a full description of the image data fed into that part of the code (e.g. the output image is a 32bpp raw RGBA file in memory as a NumPy array of shape `(4000,6000,4)` and dtype `u1`).

Comment: I added some code steps showing read/write steps. Do you think that by using the same file for reading/writing makes a big difference? Is it better to use two different files? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you are writing from multiple processes to the same HDF5 file at the same time.  In general, that is not allowed by HDF5 (it may corrupt your data).  Try writing to a separate output file per process and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, I thought that writing from multiple processes to the same HDF5 file was allowed in parallel hdf5. I tested it on a small dataset of `60` images and write one file for process took `474.3` and to the same hdf5 took `695.12`. BTW the reading was also slow: `505.59`

Comment: Try without `driver` and `comm` when opening the output file.  Just use a regular HDF5 file handle.  Also, are you really writing with compression?  It doesn't look like it.

Comment: As you suggested the process is much faster when multiple hdf5 are created. However also writing in parallel to a second file, different from the one used for reading increase the speed.

Comment: Which compression algorithm do you use (there are huge differences in speed)? What is the sequential io-speed of your storage system and what speed do you get in your example (you should get close to that if you do everything right)?

Comment: When I run parallel writing no compression is allowed. In serial writing I use .lzma. I tested different compression and .lzma was giving a good compromise between speed and file size reduction. I will look into the sequential io speed of the system.